# How to convert all 100,000 columns of cyclical time data (HH:MM:SS) to seconds?

Tags: python

I have a table called DF1 with more than 100,000 columns.

```
    device_id             time       x        y      z
ghXzbQTyASMwePeQJXQ     00:04:23   1787.4   -2.1   4992.7
                        00:16:51   9757.3   -4.1   4922.0
                        00:25:47   3337.4   -2.2   4132.4
bLXzbQTyASMxeP6QJXQ     00:36:24   6957.2   -1.8   1342.9
                        00:47:20   2956.8   -3.7   7942.8
                                :
                                :
```

I want to convert all of the data in the 'time' column from HH:MM:SS to seconds.

I ran this function (which I got from a similar question asked)

```
def get_sec(time_str):
    """Get Seconds from time."""
    h, m, s = time_str.split(':')
    return int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s)
```

And called it using each of the following codes separately.

```
get_sec(DF23[time])

get_sec(DF23.time)
```

However, each produced the following errors respectively:

```
<module 'time' (built-in)>

'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'time'
```

How can I apply the function to the entire 'time' column to change all HH:MM:SS data into seconds or alternatively is there another and more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: I am sure the error message in the `get_sec(DF23[time])` case is different.

Comment: is this pandas?

Comment: I double checked the error message for get_sec(DF23[time]) and it is KeyError: <module 'time' (built-in)>

Comment: Yes apologies for not specifying, it is in Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are curious, the answer is:

DF1['time'] = DF1['time'].apply(lambda x: ((x.hour*60+x.minute)*60+x.second)/60)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a string as column identifier:

```
get_sec(DF23['time'])
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! Unfortunately it produced an error - KeyError: 'time'

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.to_timedelta` and then `dt.total_seconds()`

**Ex:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'time':["00:04:23", "00:16:51", "00:25:47"]})
df1['seconds'] = pd.to_timedelta(df1['time']).dt.total_seconds()

print(df1)
```

**Output:**

```
       time  seconds
0  00:04:23    263.0
1  00:16:51   1011.0
2  00:25:47   1547.0
```